# Specify one generic parameter, infer the rest?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I have an interface, which is use by repositories) that with this member:

```
T FindById<T, TId>(TId id)
    where T : class, IEntity<TId>
    where TId : IEquatable<TId>;
```

This allows the caller to specify an entity type (`T`) and the type of it's `Id` field (`TId`). The implementor of this interface would then find the entities of type `T` and use the `id` parameter to filter them according to their id (which is defined on `IEntity<TId>`).

Currently I'm calling it like this:

```
int id = 123;
var myApproval = PartsDC.FindById<Approval, int>(id);
```

Ideally I'd like to do this:

```
int id = 123;
var myApproval = PartsDC.FindById<Approval>(id);
```

I figure the 2nd generic parameter should be able to be inferred by the fact that `id` is an `int` (so that's what my 2nd generic parameter is).

Is it possible to get anything like this, where I don't have to specify the type of the id field in my class?